# Sql query with datetime and BETWEEN clause

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have room slot available from '2017-06-13 00:00:00' to '2017-06-13 23:00:00'

I ran two queries:

1.

```
SELECT * FROM hs_room_slots_tbl
WHERE hs_room_slots_tbl.from BETWEEN '2017-06-12 22:00:00' AND  '2017-06-13 21:00:00' 
   OR  hs_room_slots_tbl.to BETWEEN '2017-06-13 02:00:00' AND  '2017-06-14 01:00:00'
```

2.

```
SELECT * FROM hs_room_slots_tbl
WHERE hs_room_slots_tbl.from BETWEEN '2017-06-13 03:00:00' AND  '2017-06-13 08:00:00' 
   OR  hs_room_slots_tbl.to BETWEEN '2017-06-13 07:00:00' AND  '2017-06-13 12:00:00'
```

First query fetches the slot and second one is supposed to fetch the slot right? I am not getting why the second query is not fetching the result.

Edit: This is the record
[image]

Comment: but do you have the data in that range?

Comment: @MichaelO Yes the slot is there with data in that range

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data in hs_room_slots_tbl.from and hs_room_slots_tbl.to that you expect to match?

Comment: As far as I can see both queries are the same but with different date/time parameters. SO if 1. works then 2. should work assuming the data in the database exists

Comment: @BartonChittenden There is a record with hs_room_slots_tbl.from as '2017-06-13 00:00:00' and hs_room_slots_tbl.to as '2017-06-13 23:00:00'. The first query is generated when from and to are '2017-06-13 00:00:00' and '2017-06-13 23:00:00'. The second query is generated when from and to are '2017-06-13 05:00:00' and '2017-06-13 10:00:00' respectively

Comment: What you get if you select only `BETWEEN '2017-06-13 03:00:00' AND '2017-06-13 12:00:00'`  ?

Comment: @MichaelO. No result is fetched if from is '2017-06-13 03:00:00' and to is '2017-06-13 12:00:00' as well!

Comment: So you have no data there

Comment: @MichaelO. I have updated the question with the data

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second query, your need the `from` to be in range:

```
BETWEEN '2017-06-13 03:00:00' AND  '2017-06-13 08:00:00'
```

and it's 2017-06-13 00:00:00, so its not in the range (the data is in hour 0 and you need it greater than 3), so it doesn't match
The same with the `to`, you need it

```
BETWEEN '2017-06-13 07:00:00' AND  '2017-06-13 12:00:00'
```

and you have it at 23 ('2017-06-13 23:00:00')that it's not in the range. The data is 23 and the range it's from 07-12

So the second query is working right, it doesn have to fetch the data